# How to use jQuery AJAX to Update ASP.NET MVC View Data？

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Index.html:

```
@{
    var SWList = ViewData["SWList"] as List<Fostudio.Model.Software.Softwares>;
}

<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="$.getScript('/Software/Index?SWType=文本编辑');">文本编辑</button>
</div>


<div class="row">
@{
    foreach (var item in SWList)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4" style="margin: 10px 0">
            <div class="card text-center">
                <div class="card-header">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
                </div>
                <div class="card-block" style="margin: 10px 0;">
                    <h4 class="card-title" style="margin: 10px 0"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h4>
                    <p class="card-text" style="height: 40px;"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>
                    <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.URL)" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width: 150px; margin: 10px 0;">Get it</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ChangeSW(SWType) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Software/Index',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { SWType: SWType },
    });
}
```

SoftwareController:

```
public class SoftwareController : Controller
{
    private SoftwaresBLL softwareBLL = SoftwaresBLL.GetInstance();

    public ActionResult Index(string SWType = "")
    {
        if (SWType != "")
        {
            List<Softwares> SoftwaresList = softwareBLL.GetList("where Type=@0", SWType);
            ViewData["SWList"] = SoftwaresList;
            return RedirectToAction("Software", "Index");
        }
        else
        {
            List<Softwares> allSoftwaresList = softwareBLL.GetList();
            ViewData["SWList"] = allSoftwaresList;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to click a button and update the model list data shown in the view. I have been debugging and made sure the data is passed, but my view is not updated. I wanted to know if it is good practice to do that or if there is a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pass the model directly to the view using the View(model) function? If so, you could probably avoid the need for jQuery & ViewData here.

Comment: @Jack I didn't quite understand what you said. Could you be more specific? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this MSDN article that explains one way of how to pass a model to a view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Comment: Ajax calls cannot redirect, so your `return RedirectToAction("Software", "Index");` line of code makes no sense. And you not doing anything with the view you return back to the client - you need to update the DOM in the success callback